# Use Raspberry Pi as NAS and Media Center (OpenELEC, RaspBMC,..)

Tags: networking, raspbmc, openelec

I want to use my raspberry pi as a NAS and media center. I have a Samsung smart TV and today I start my computer and watch films over DLNA.

I want to attach the Raspberry Pi with a USB HDD to the network.

Should I use something like OpenELEC or RaspBMC (because all I read is that I have to connect it by HDMI - is it possible over network?). Or what other software do you suggest?

I also want to use it as backup drive over in the network with something like  Crashplan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want use your RPi as NAS you should read this:
http://elinux.org/R-Pi_NAS

If you want use your RPi as Media Center you should read this:
http://elinux.org/RPi_XBMC

You can do all this in one system.

Comment: I have no experience with xmbc. 1) Do I have to connect it with hdmi-cable or can it stream over network? 2) Does this provide dlna-access?

Comment: I think you shoud use HDMI cable, becouse RPi has 10/100 Ethernet. This is enough for stream FullHD, but when you stream (dlna) fullHD you don't have enough bandwitdh for NAS functions.

Comment: Yes you can setup XBMC as DLNA server, but you have limited bandwidht. So i think RPi don't know serve lot 2-3 or more client at same time.

Comment: Ok. Today I use my Computer as NAS and stream it over network to tv. So bandwidth should be no problem.

Comment: 1080p video streaming is minimum need ~24-35 Mbps bandwidth. It is smaller than 100 Mbps. So you can stream out a 1080p video, but if you want stream other thing this is not enough i think.